# Rails 4: Set a cookie in a request/response if type is JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, cookies

How do I set a cookie when responding to a request of type application/json in Rails?

The controller action works as expected but there is no cookie being set and there is no Set-Cookie header in the response.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            log_in(user)
            .
            .
            cookies[:test] = 'Test cookie'

            render json: @user
            #render json: @user, set_cookie: 'test' #Also tried this
        else
            render text: 'Wrong username and/or password', status: 401
        end
    end

end
```

Route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    .
    .
    resources :sessions, :defaults => { :format => :json }

end
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me in Rails 4.2.0, perhaps the issue is that the browser in question doesn't return the cookie to you. Why do you think Rails isn't responding with the cookie? Have you tried using `curl` to see the headers?

Answer (score 15):

I am encountering the same problem. 
Here is how I solved:

```
response.set_cookie "name", "nic"
```

I also came up with the cause of the problem. It is the forgery protection that null the session just before the response is composed.

To use the `cookies` methods, you need to skip the auth validation of the token:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: Make sure you set `path=/`

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly then this is a really bad idea. This leaves your site vulnerable to cross domain attacks that aren't then verified to be from one of your own logged in users. Instead of skipping the verification you instead want to ensure that you are sending the CSRF token with the JSON request.